# Redefine \choose as \binom

Tags: definition

I did not know that I should be using `\binom` instead of `\choose` (and I ignored all the warnings). Now, instead of manually changing it at all places where I used `\choose`, I think there should be a way to *redefine* `\choose` as `\binom` right?

However, I don't know how and cannot find how to do it.

Comment: the syntax is different, the main argument against `\choose` is the infix syntax (the final result is the same) so either leave it as it is or a simple editor replace should change the source code, there is no way to do anything in tex

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX? Please also tell us how you employ `\choose`. E.g., do you always enclose the full expression in curly braces, as in `{ 5 \choose 3 }`?

Comment: @Mico even with luatex, using an input buffer callback to change \choose to \binom which then expands essentially to \choose seems a bit round-about.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Indeed, the simplest solution seems to do a find-replace. @Mico - yes, I am able to use LuaLaTex and yes I always enclose the expression in curly braces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Indeed, the OP should just edit his/her file and manually replace all `\choose` constructs in suitable ways.

Comment: If always between curly brackets, I guess a RegEx find+replace tool could make it quite easy even for many occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always enclose the infix-style arguments of `\choose` in curly braces, i.e., if you write `${n \choose k}$` rather than just `$n \choose k$`, the following LuaLaTeX-based approach may be of interest to you. It defines a Lua function and assigns it to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback to scan the input stream for instances of `{...\choose...}` and to convert them to equivalent `\binom` expressions *before* TeX starts its usual processing.

This approach does have a few limitations. In particular, it assumes that the two `...` arguments of `\choose` don't contain further curly braces. A less-binding constraint, hopefully, is that the instances of `{...\choose...}` don't contain line breaks.

[image]

If you check the log file, you'll find that it doesn't contain any warnings of the type

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 13.
```

That's because by the time LaTeX processes the input, it never "sees" any of the `\choose` instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\binom' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function choose2binom ( s )
   -- perform non-greedy pattern match for "1 or more instances of any character"
   return ( s:gsub ( "{(..-)\\choose(..-)}" , "\\binom{%1}{%2}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
    "process_input_buffer", choose2binom , "choose2binom" ) }}

\begin{document}
${5\choose3}$ ${ 10 \choose 4 }$ $ {n\choosek} $
\end{document}
```